# Unexpected behavior when converting String to TIMESTAMP in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I've been working with **GridDB** and exploring its capabilities concerning *data management* and *retrieval*. I recently encountered an unexpected behavior when attempting to convert a `STRING` type to a `TIMESTAMP` type using the provided TQL commands.

I have a container with a schema where one of the columns is defined as STRING.
I've been storing date-time values in this STRING column in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.
I decided to convert this STRING column to a TIMESTAMP column to use the time-series functionalities of GridDB better.
I used the following TQL command to alter the container schema:

`ALTER TABLE my_container ALTER COLUMN date_column TYPE TIMESTAMP;`

After executing the above command, I noticed that the date-time values stored in the date_column were not correctly converted to TIMESTAMP values. Instead, they seemed to be interpreted as integer values, which resulted in incorrect TIMESTAMP values.

I referred to the [GridDB TQL reference](https://docs.griddb.net/tqlreference/type/#primitive) but could not find a detailed explanation on data type conversions, specifically from STRING to TIMESTAMP.

**My question is;**

Is there a specific TQL command or function that should be used to correctly convert STRING values to TIMESTAMP values in GridDB?